# Data imbalance issue in multi label output

Tags: python, keras, imbalanced-data

I have an image dataset where two images (left eye and right eye) image have the same multi-label.

In order to handle the image, I used two ResNet and concatenated their last layers. After that, I use Dense layer and output layer with 8 neurons and `sigmoid` activation. `Binary Cross Entropy` is used as loss function.

Problem is that I am having imbalance dataset issue.
Is there any way to handle this.

[image]